# Spring load specific properties into a properties object

Tags: spring, properties

My `application.properties`contains the following properties :

```
db.username = ...
db.password = ...
db.timeout = ...

rest.client.username = ...
rest.client.password = ...
rest.client.timeout = ...
```

I would like to load only the rest client's properties into a configuration

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

....

private Properties restProperties; // << here should go 3 properties with prefix rest.client

}
```

Any way to do it in Java Based Configurations ?

Answer (score 1):

If you move your all of your `rest.client` properties into their own properties file (e.g. `restclient.properies`), you can use [PropertiesLoaderUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderUtils.html):

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/restclient.properties");
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

Alternatively, you can use [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/2.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html), as seen [here](http://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot), but it won't be a `Properties` object, but rather, an object that you define yourself.

Also, I feel like it might be worth mentioning that you can add

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
```

and access any properties by using

```
env.getProperty("your.property.here")
```